# Inapp purchase discount using template

Tags: google-api, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

For Android in app purchasing module...
I am following guidelines as given on [Official Page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1153481)

I wish to present 4-5 non-consumable digital goods within my app.

So for each digital product I have created a [pricing template](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373#pricing_template)

But if the user of my app wants to purchase all of the products, I wish to offer discount.
I suppose, I can create an additional discount template & bind all the digital goods sku in combination for that purpose.

My question is **how can I handle the combinations** arising out of the sold product purchases.

Eg:
If user makes 1 purchase in first month (any 1 product of 5) and later wishes to purchase all in the next month...how I apply the discount in that case.

All my 5/6 products are of varying prices..so it generates many combinations.

I do not find [promos](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/promo) applicable in my case

Comment: Another way to look at it would be, I want a put a ceiling to the maximum amount user pays me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-app products only have one price, there is no possibility of applying discounts, Google in-app billing does not support it.

If you want to offer a product with two different prices, you will have to create two different products in the Play Console and your code will have to decide which of the two the user will buy.

Pricing templates are used to set the same price on several products even in different apps, not to set discounts.

It is possible to offer a product for a sale price for a period of time but this is not what you are looking for.